# LEFT JOIN in SQL. How to exclude all the rows from the T1 in T2?

Tags: sql, join, left-join, not-exists

T1 - table one with only one column

```
Bart
Philip
Beth
```

T2 - table two with only one column

```
Robert
Bart
Philip
Ann
Jack
Helen
Beth
```

The expected result after JOIN is:

```
Robert
Ann
Jack
Helen
```

Comment: What have you tried, why can you not join the tables?

Comment: I have tried left and right joins and I can merge them together, but I can't remove all the rows in T2 from T1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are after is a simple `outer join`

```
select t2.col 
from t2
left join t1 on t2.col=t1.col
where t1.col is null
```

You can also express it as a `not exists`

```
select * 
from t2
where not exists(select 1 from t1 where t2.col=t1.col)
```

You can also express it using `except`

```
select * 
from t2
except
select * 
from t1
```